# Google Spreadsheets npm overwrite rows instead of appending

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am using [google-spreadsheets npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet), and using the method `addRows()` I would like to overwrite the exisitng rows on a given sheet, but for some reason it keeps appending, I have read the [documentation](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-worksheet?id=working-with-rows) and even thou there is an option to insert, which metions about overwritting, it does not work.

I have also tried to use the `row.delete()` to remove each row one at the time before writting but it fails after deleting very slowly some of them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to overwrite the rows to the existing rows. This is the question 1.
- You want to delete the multiple rows with the low process cost. This is the question 2.
- You want to achieve above using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

### Answer for question 1:

In this sample script, the rows 3 and 4 of the 1st sheet of `spreadsheetId` are overwritten by `values`.

#### Modified script:

```
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetIndex = 0; // Please set the sheet index. This sample uses `0`.
const values = [["A1", "B1", "C1"], ["A2", "B2", "C2"]]; // Please set the values you want to overwrite.
const overwriteRowNumber = 3; // Please set the start row number you want to overwrite. In this sample, "values" overwrites from the row 3.

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId);
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
await doc.loadInfo();
const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[sheetIndex];
const rows = await sheet.getRows({offset: overwriteRowNumber - 2, limit: values.length});
rows.forEach(async (row, i) => {
  const existingColLen = row._rawData.length;
  const valueColLen = values[i].length;
  row._rawData = existingColLen > valueColLen ? values[i].concat(Array(existingColLen - valueColLen).fill("")) : values[i];
  await row.save();
});
```

- But, in this case, it seems that the method of "spreadsheets.values.update" is used every loop. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/1da839dc690b79c6aa735e2faccea8b3c0fca9b0/lib/GoogleSpreadsheetRow.js#L35) And, although I was looking for the method for batchUpdate for this situation, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. So as a workaround, I would like to propose the following sample script. In this script, the access token is retrieved from the authorization script for google-spreadsheet and it directly requests to the endpoint of the method of spreadsheets.values.update using the request module. So please add `const requests = require("request");`.

  ```
    const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
    const values = [["A1", "B1", "C1"], ["A2", "B2", "C2"]]; // Please set the values you want to overwrite.
    const overwriteRange = "Sheet1!A3"; // Please set the 1st range you want to overwrite as a1Notation.

    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId);
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
    requests.put(
    {
      url: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${doc.spreadsheetId}/values/${overwriteRange}?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${doc.jwtClient.credentials.access_token}`,
       ,
      body: JSON.stringify({ values: values }),
    },
    (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(body);
    });
  ```

  - In this sample script, `values` is put to `Sheet1!A3` as the overwrite by one API call.

### Answer for question 2:

In this sample script, the multiple rows in the sheet of `spreadsheetId` are deleted. Unfortunately, in this case, the row is deleted every row using Sheets API. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/1da839dc690b79c6aa735e2faccea8b3c0fca9b0/lib/GoogleSpreadsheetRow.js#L55) And, although I was looking for the method for batchUpdate for this situation, unfortunately, I couldn't also find it. So as a workaround, I would like to propose the following sample script. In this script, the access token is retrieved from the authorization script for google-spreadsheet and it directly requests to the endpoint of the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the row 3 and 4 in the sheet ID `0` of `spreadsheetId` are deleted by one API call.

```
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
const requestBody = {
  requests: [
    {
      deleteDimension: {
        range: {
          sheetId: 0, // Please set the sheet ID.
          dimension: "ROWS",
          startIndex: 2, // Please set the start index of row you want to delete.
          endIndex: 4, // Please set the end index of row you want to delete.
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId);
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
requests.post(
{
  url: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${doc.spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate`,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${doc.jwtClient.credentials.access_token}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
},
(err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(body);
});
```

### References:

- [Document of google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I actually was more inclined to start from point 3 using the google-spreedsheet wrapper form npm. In the end I fixed it by doing `spreadsheet.clear()` followed by `spreadsheet.setHeaderRow()` to replicate the headers and then `spreadsheet.addRows()`

Comment: @Álvaro Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I couldn't understand about your current issue for my answer. I apologize for this again. If my answer has the issues, could you please tell me them? I would like to modify them.

Comment: Your answer seems to be using the google sheets API directly, whereas I am using the google-spreadsheet npm wrapper

Comment: @Álvaro Thank you for replying. Yes. I understood it. So in my answer, I proposed the script using "google-spreadsheet". But, now, it seems that in order to reduce the process cost of the script, "google-spreadsheet" doesn't use the batch request. So as the additional proposal, I added the sample script for using the endpoint of Sheets API. I think that googleapis for Node.js can be also used. But I'm not sure whether you can use googleapis. 
 So I proposed to directly request to the endpoint. If my additional proposal was not useful for your situation, I apologize.